# Redirect based on Country but allow if IP is whitelisted

Tags: php, redirect, geo

I have a script that Redirects people from my country and allow all others to stay if not my country.

How can I whitelist my IP address to stay if its from the country which should redirect all?

````
require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
// create a variable for the country code
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
// redirect based on country code:
if ($var_country_code == "BG") {
   header('Location: https://wikipedia.org/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "E1") {
   header('Location: https://website.xyz/wordpress');

}
?>```
````

Comment: If you have a static ip.assign it to a variable and compare it along with country code. If dynamic, Find your IP address online and add a comparison check in the else if loop

Comment: What keeps you from adding more conditions to the script?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to get client IP then check against your IP (if it is STATIC)
and if it is TRUE then you may not redirect if not(else) get there location and continue with the rest of your code

```
if (client_IP == "Your own IP") {
   header('Location: Whatever location you want');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "BG") {
   header('Location: https://wikipedia.org/');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "E1") {
   header('Location: https://pasted.xyz/wordpress');
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Its redirecting me to wikipedia still... its like not whitelisting my IP from the function to redirect BG Country code people.

Comment: what code you used and is still not working?
and are you sure your IP is static?

Comment: Yes i am sure its static.
The script works, but the ClientIP is from BG but redirect me to wikipedia, instead of the Link i want to redirect.

Comment: I think you didn't get what I mean, you are going to hardcode your IP address in the script and compare the client IP not a country just his numerical IP against the one you hard-coded in the script and it's not going to evaluate to TRUE if it's not you (we hope)

Comment: what function did you use yo get the client IP?
you know that "if (client_IP == "Your own IP") code doesn't work "
is like pseudo-code, not the actual code?

Comment: Can you get me the Client IP function to use and make it work?